как проверять, содержит ли текст название ключа json?
def get_token():
url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/USER/autorization/main/ez.json"
headers = CaseInsensitiveDict()
headers["Authorization"] = "token TOKEN"
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
if response.status_code == 200:
    data = response.json()
    os.system('cls')
    get = input('Введите ключ: ')
    if get == data["codes"]:
        if a == data["codes"][get]["hwid"]:
            helper()
        else:
            bruh=data["codes"][get]["resets"]
            gey = input(f"Неверный HWID! У вас осталось {bruh}шт. сбрасыванний HWID. Хотите сбросить?\n1. Да\n2. Выход")
            if gey == "1":
                print("ок")
            elif gey == "2":
                os.system('break')
    else:
        print("Неверный код!")
        get_token()
else:
    return {'error': f"Ошибка: {response.status_code}"}

у меня есть json таблица
{"codes": {"juUjehjalSe": {"hwid": "secret","reset": 1}, "IoehStehakRe": {"hwid": "secret","reset": 1}}}

и мне нужно проверять, если get совпадает с "juUjehjalSe" в "codes", то его пропускало.
так как я буду добавлять много кодов, то мне нужно сделать так, чтобы он искал совпадения а после пропускал пользователя.
если что-то не поняли, попросите меня поправить или уточнить.

if get in data["codes"].keys(): что-то такое вам нужно?

@Amgarak можно и без .keys() :)

@ClarkDevlin действительно :)

спасибо большое, помогло
